# how to use json data inside list in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

i want to upload data in form of json inside list 
example:

```
create table product (product_details list<text>,
                      location varchar,
                      primarykey(location));

Insert into product(product_details,location)
                   values(
                    [
                    {"productname": "xyz"},
                    {"price":"100"}
                    ],
                    'bangalore'
                   );
```

It is showing errors

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: SyntaxException: line 1:99 no viable alternative at input '}' (... values ([                     {"productname": ["xy]z"}...)

Comment: Your error message code seems to differ with your code.

Comment: no, same command only i used for creating and inserting

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have syntax error in create table query for primary key. And next problem you can try insert value for not `list<text>` type, based on value change your type to `list<frozen<map<text,text>>>`.

So change create table query to:

```
create table product (product_details list<frozen<map<text,text>>>, location varchar, primary key(location));
```

And fix insert query double quotes to single, should be:

```
insert into product (product_details, location) values([{'productname':'xyz'}, {'price':'100'}], 'bangalore');
```